# Время выполнения итераций постоянно растёт

Tags: php, worker

Добрый вечер дорогие пользователи,
Нужна ваша помощь, я написал, грубо говоря, воркер, который берёт данный из файла используя следю команду *tail -n+x path/to/file | head -n50*, но при каждой повторной итераций время выполнения скрипта увеличивается

Пример кода:

```
$p = 'UploadFiles/million_test.txt';
$l = 0;
$i = 0;
$start = microtime(true);
do {
    $command = "tail -n+$l $p | head -n50";
    exec($command, $data);

    $count = count($data);
    if ($count == 0) {
        die;
    }
    $i++;
    $l += 500;

    if ($i % 100 == 0) {
        file_put_contents(
            'test.txt',
            "$l [$count] =>" . round((microtime(true) - $start), 2) .
            PHP_EOL,
            FILE_APPEND
        );
        $start = microtime(true);
    }
    unset($data);
} while ($count > 0);
```

Данные выполнения скрипта

`50000 [50] =>0.71
100000 [50] =>0.9
150000 [50] =>1.09
200000 [50] =>1.19
250000 [50] =>1.35
300000 [50] =>1.44
350000 [50] =>1.58
400000 [50] =>1.66
450000 [50] =>1.65`

Как вы можете видеть, спустя пару итераций время выполнение скрипта увеличивалось в 2 раза.
Может кто-то знает что я делаю не так?
Или хотя-бы дайте намёк что на почитать, буду очень плагодарен.

В файле *million_test.txt* около 12 миллионов записей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$command = "tail -n+$l $p | head -n50";
exec($command, $data);
```

команда считывает из файла все(-n+$l) строк, а потом берет верхнюю их часть(-n50)
сам подход очень медленный.
`file($p)` для этого подойдет много лучше, ниже сравнительный тест по скорости чтения сгенерированого файла на 1м строк

```
весь файл прочитан функцией file($p) за 0.01сек 

далее произведено чтение файла по частям при помощи exec("trail ....")
Array
(
    [50_5000] => 0.03
    [50_10000] => 0.03
    [50_15000] => 0.03
    [50_20000] => 0.03
    [50_25000] => 0.03
    [50_30000] => 0.03
    [50_35000] => 0.04
    [50_40000] => 0.04
    [50_45000] => 0.04
    [50_50000] => 0.04
    [50_55000] => 0.04
    [50_60000] => 0.04
    [50_65000] => 0.04
    [50_70000] => 0.04
    [50_75000] => 0.05
    [50_80000] => 0.05
    [50_85000] => 0.05
    [50_90000] => 0.05
    [50_95000] => 0.05
    [50_100000] => 0.05
)
```

Comment: Дело в том что я должен отправлять данные на другом сервере, и что бы сделать это быстрее я хочу запустить 5 скриптов который будут делать запросы на сервер и отправлять данные

Comment: распишите задачу подробнее, может подскажу альтернативное решение

Answer (score 1):

В общем-то это все объяснимо. Вероятней всего время итерации увеличивается из-за того что дольше работает команда tail. Т.е. тут проблема не вашем коде, а в  том как **tail** работает.

Т.е. когда вы "просите" выдать вам последние 500 строк из файла, то команда считывает эти 500 строк и выводит. Когда вы просите выдать следующие 500 строк, то команда считывает 1000 строк и выводит их, а потом через **head** вы берете из них только пятьсот.

На следующей итерации **tail** считывает уже 1500 строк. И т.д. и т.п. Чем ближе к началу файла, тем больше строк нужно считать и выдать, тем дольше работает команда.

В данной реализации с этим ничего не поделать. Не совсем понятно какую вы задачу решаете. Но возможно более оптимально и быстро будет открыть этот файл  средствами PHP и построчно его прочитать за один раз. И разбить на блоки, если это нужно. Или сделать что-то еще.